# SP2013 - Hide web part error if user is not authorized

Tags: 2013, web-part

I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013.

I've a page with many web parts that refer to document libraries. For each DL I've set specific authorizations.

Some users can see everything, so this is not a problem. Other user are authorized only on its DL (e.g.: User 1 can see/upload files only on DL 1).

When I try to login with this user (User 1) I see this error on a Web Part that correctly is "hidden":

> Web Part Error: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform
>   this action or access this resource.

Is it possible to hide this error if user is not authorized to see the DL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you mean access and not authorization. Authorization tells SharePoint who you are, and Access tells SharePoint what permission you (the authorized user) have.

Apart from that, it's possible to create audiences in the User Profile Service, which you can filter from any property in Active Directory. If you target a specific audience, and another user comes along, not belonging to the audience, the user won't see the web part.

So you're on the right track. Create an audience in UPSA and filter web parts based on audience.

Comment: Thanks Benny! Are UPSA and/or audiences available on SP Foundation?

Comment: @Pepozzo Unfortunately not. You'd need at least standard edition of SharePoint to user UPSA.